# how to create a Context Menu from other ContextMenu's ToolStripMenuItems in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a ContextMenuStrip in my c# win application that include some submenu.

How i can display a existing submenu(from above ContextMenuStrip) on a button when this clicked?

Comment: i have a ContextMenu that contents of subContextMenus and i want to display one of that subContextMenu on my button when that clicked

Answer (score 0):

Takle munu first and add menu items into it e.g delete or resize and after that take e.g take resize menu item and add items into it like submenu1 and submenu2

```
            menu = new ContextMenu();
            mnudel = new MenuItem("Delete");
            mnuresize = new MenuItem("Resize");
            menu.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { mnudel, mnuresize });
               submenu1 = new MenuItem("Sub1");
            submenu2 = new MenuItem("Sub2");
            mnuresize.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { submenu1, submenu2 })
```

Comment: i have a ContextMenu that contents of subContextMenus and i want to display one of that subContextMenu on my button when that clicked